# find value of enabled textarea by class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have two textarea with same class and different id. At a time only one is enabled. I need to save enabled textarea value to database using ajax. But i have no idea about how to find value of enabled textarea.

Here is my code :

```js
 $('#messageTransactionalUnicode').attr('disabled', 'true');
    $('#save-template-transactional').click(function() {
        $('#messageTransactionalError').text(''); 
        if($('.messageTransactional').val() == ''){
            $('#messageTransactionalError').text('required');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            var templateText = $('.messageTransactional').val(); 
            //alert(templateText);
            $.ajax({
                url : base_url + 'SMS/SaveTemplate',
                type : 'POST',
                data : {templateText : templateText, type: 'transactional' },
                success:function(data) {
                    if(data == 1){
                        notification('Template submitted successfully', 'success');
                    }
                    else{
                        notification('An error occured, please try again', 'failure');
                    }
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="messageTransactional" name="messageTransactional" id="messageTransactionalEnglish" placeholder="Enter your message here.." maxlength="160" ></textarea>
<textarea class="messageTransactional" name="messageTransactional" id="messageTransactionalUnicode" placeholder="Enter your message here.." style="display: none;" maxlength="70" ></textarea>
<button class="save-template" id="save-template-transactional" type="button">Save Template</button>
```

I have a dropdown, and in it's change event I can disable and enable these two textarea like a toggle function. That part is working, but `var templateText = $('.messageTransactional').val();` will always displays first textarea value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the combined selectors [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:disabled`](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) for that :

```
var templateText = $('.messageTransactional:not(:disabled)').val();
                                             ^     ^
                                        Grab |the disabled textarea
                                             |
                                      Grab the opposite
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below to get value of enabled element using [`:enabled`](https://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/) selector in your case:

```
var templateText = $('.messageTransactional:enabled').val();
```